# How can I play PokemonGo on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, games, compatibility

Ubuntu at the moment has two platforms;

- **Ubuntu** (Unity7) 12.04 - 16.04

and

- **Ubuntu Touch** (Unity8) Phone, Tablet, and 16.10+

How does one play PokemonGo on either of these platforms?

Comment: Maybe you can set up an Android_x86 VM on Ubuntu and run it in there? It works for Whatsapp (using that myself), but that does not need GPS or location services and I don't know if those can be emulated that easily.

Answer (score 4):

Eventually there will be open source clones of Pokémon GO and sometime after that something like Tux GO will be ported to Ubuntu Phone. You can catch a warthog, badger, drake, eft, fawn, gibbon, heron, ibex, jackalope, koala, lynx, meerkat, narwhale, ocelot, pangolin, quetzal, ringtail, salamander, tahr, unicorn, vervet, werewolf and xerus and save it to your Tuxdex.

This project may be delayed due to technical difficulties caused by an insufficient number of animals, however it could be solved by either inventing new animals or by augmenting the Tuxdex with fish and different species of penguins.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Android SDK which is available here: [Android Studio SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)
. From there, you'd download the Pokemon GO APK which I cannot provide a link to as I am unsure of the safety/security of any of them, but I'm sure there's plenty you can find after just a quick google search. Install the APK to the Android SDK and you run it. It's pretty much like having a virtual Android Phone on your computer. There is no way to install it natively though.

Comment: Got a screenshot of it working?

Comment: No I don't. I've had absolutely no desire to do this myself xD. I do have the SDK installed for Android app development which is why I know this works. The only issues you'd likely encounter is location services. It's usually dependent on your hardware. The only way to know is to try.

Answer (score 0):

Pokemon GO cant be played in Ubuntu cause , it is not available for any desktop/laptop operating system , even if you can install it with emulators like genymotion (Android_x86 wont work here). It will not run cause GPS signal will be unavailable.

Again think practically, will anyone walk in the streets with their laptops open? There is a reason this games are only made for phones.

It is still not released for Ubuntu Phone and most probably it will not but dont loose your hopes.

Comment: I know you said prob not, but that was in 2016 and it's 2021 now. This is only my first search result, but any updates? can't hurt this thread